# Sort table alphabetically

Tags: reactjs, function, sorting

I have a table with numbers and words. I want to sort it by clicking on head title.

I already had a function to sort numbers but the function for words doesn't work.

I've try localeCompare and sort function like this:

```
data2.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[id] < b[id]) return -1;
      if (a[id] > b[id]) return 1;
      return 0;
```

localCompare function:

```
sortowanieNazwy = (id) => {
    const { data2} = this.state;

    data2.sort((a, b) => a[id].localeCompare(b[id]))
    this.setState({ data2 })

  }
```

I'm getting data from API like this:

```
axios
    .get("http://localhost/api?", {params : {rok : this.state.rok, }, headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ this.state.token }})
    .then(response =>
      response.data.map(data2 => ({
        IDA: `${data2.id}`,
        Pozycja: `${data2.pozycja}`,
        ...

      }))
    )
    .then(data2 => {
        this.setState({ data2 });
      }
    })
}
```

and making table:

```
data2.map(user => {
  const { IDA...} = user;
  return (
     <>
     <tr id={IDA}>
        <td ><p>{Dzial}</p></td>
        ...

     </tr>
```

Function localeCompare works in 90%, first 2/3 rows don't sort correctly.
I'm sorting the red column. Firts 3 row are empty, then is a text starting with D, then text starting with Z and then rest of the table is sorted correctly.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn6dp.png)

After sorting, I'm maping a Table using .map function

I'm from Poland so a need to sort also a polish letters. I'm using UTF-8.

Comment: Could you give an example? Because `localeCompare` should work.

Comment: Show more code please

Comment: i've add screen and my localCompare function

Answer (score 0):

[localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/localeCompare) works perfectly:

```js
const alphabet = _.shuffle(['a', 'ą', 'b', 'c', 'ć', 'd', 'e', 'ę', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'ł', 'm', 'n', 'ń', 'o', 'ó', 'p', 'r', 's', 'ś', 't', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'z', 'ź', 'ż'])
console.log('Shuffled: ', alphabet.toString())

alphabet.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
console.log('Sorted: ', alphabet.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i've try localCompare and it doesn't work as you can see on the print-screen

Comment: Could you provide a working example an any sandbox?

Comment: i'm getting a table data from local api so the code won't work :/

Comment: But at least a piece of code where you reproduce the problem? Otherwise we will not be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, which part of code will be helpful? I'm getting a data prom API by axios, then i map it to table whit head in which is onClick={() => this.sortowanieNazwy('Opis')} function. i've add a map funtion and get funtion.

Comment: Did you try to move the comparison in your axios call (just before setting the state)?

Comment: You mean to sort data after axios call? i want to sort the table only when user click the head text.